# How to use `GoToAsync()` from PuppeteerSharp to support local path but not with https?

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp, azure-linux

I am using PuppeteerSharp in C#.

I would like to use `await page.GoToAsync(localPath);` but faced below exception:

```
Protocol error (Page.navigate): Cannot navigate to invalid URL
```

How can I support browsing local path instead of HTTPS?

Comment: What URL are you trying to use?

Comment: hi hardkoded, I would like to access FunctionProject/www/index.html
It is solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For local path, need to use file protocol like below:

```
await page.GoToAsync("file://" + Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "www", "index.html"));
```